# Redshift SQL - Reverse Listagg function

Tags: sql, string, csv, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have a table like below:

```
Name   Order
 AA     1,2
 BB     2,3
```

I want my result to be like:

```
Name   Order
 AA      1
 AA      2
 BB      2
 BB      3
```

How can I achieve this in Redshift?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the data type of Order column?

Comment: @zealous suppose it's string (like actual order number A1, A2, A3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know in advance the maximum number of elements per delimited list, you can do this with a table of numbers and `split_part()`:

```
select t.name, split_part(t.order, ',', n.n) val
from (
    select 1 n
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
) n
inner join mytable t
    on n.n <= regexp_count(t.order, ',') + 1
```

you can expand derived table `n` with more numbers as needed. It is also possible to use `row_number()` against a large table to generate the numbers table.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not following the subquery n there, and the purpose of regexp_count there. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: It's basically joining the data to a table containing a count, then using that to pick a part of the split item. It's a bit of a cheat since that's not what SQL was created to do, but it does work.